# WebStorm create file from <script> tag

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I saw someone in youtube working in a JBs IDE and had a `index.html` file opened. He created the `<script src="main.js"></script>` at the bottom of the page and the IDE recognized that `main.js` did not exists on the project file structure. The file changed into a blue link, he clicked `main.js` inside the `<script>` tag and the IDE created the file in the directory and opened the file in a new window for editing. That is a nice feature. 
Does any one know how to set this up in JBs IDE?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/intention-actions.html?search=intention -- `Alt+Enter` (depends on Keymap used) while having caret on problematic place (script file name in your case) and choose right option from appeared menu.